# How to include html coming from wysihtml5 in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wysihtml5, html-safe

I have text content prepared using the wysihtml5 gem, which I would like to show in a div. Question is how to "render" this text content, as to be "safe". Should I use

```
= text.html_safe
```

or

```
= simple_format(text)
```

or

```
= raw(text)
```

or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to show everything, as it was entered in wysihtml5 (but not 100% safe), than use any of these:

```
= text.html_safe
= raw text
== text
```

If you would like to make it absolutely safe, then use:

```
== sanitize text, tags: %w(em strong b i u a ...), attributes: %w(href title ...)
```

In such way you can control tags that are allowed and allowed attributes for tags.

Comment: When I started reading about the "sanitize" method, I bumped into the "sanitize" gem as well. Any experience with that one?

Comment: No experience with this gem at all. Built-in sanitize helper works great!

Comment: It's also the first time I see the double ==. What is the difference with the single = ?

Comment: `==` is a shortcut for `= raw` :) It's simple, like that